# PHPUnit check method invoked multiple times with multiple parameters

Tags: phpunit

I have the following class:

```
class Foo
{
    public function importBars(array $array)
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $this->importBar($key, $value);
        }
    }

    public function importBar($key, $value)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I need to test that `importBar` is called `count($array)` times, *and* that it's called with the right parameters. Using `$this->at()` is not an option, as the order of the `$array` elements might change. I have:

```
public function testImportBars(array $array)
{
    // Mock invocation ...
    $logicalOrs = array();
    foreach ($array as $sku => $value) {
        $logicalOrs[] = $this->logicalOr($this->equalTo($key), $this->equalTo($value));
    }

    $mock->expects($this->exactly(count($array)))
        ->method('importBar')
        ->with(call_user_func_array(array($this, 'logicalOr'), $logicalOrs));
}
```

Which passes the tests. However, when I deliberately make it fail:

```
foreach ($array as $sku => $value) {
    $logicalOrs[] = $this->logicalOr($this->equalTo($key), $this->equalTo(null));
}
```

... it still passes. It only fails if the `$key` is incorrect:

```
foreach ($array as $sku => $value) {
    $logicalOrs[] = $this->logicalOr($this->equalTo(null), $this->equalTo(null));
}
```

... which suggests PHPUnit is only checking if the first parameter passed to `Foo::importBar()` is correct.

Is there a way to tell PHPUnit to verify arguments to methods when there is more than one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, here is the closest solution I've come up with:

```
$rows = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $rows[] = array($key, $value);
}

$method = $mock->expects($this->exactly(count($array)))
        ->method('importBar');

call_user_func_array(array($method, 'withConsecutive'), $rows);
```

See: http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects